# How do I apply a layer to multiple images in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers

I am new to graphic design, and can't figure this out. I am making a "Meet the team" page for a small business's website.  On the page will be staff portraits.  I can edit out the original background of each employee portrait, and can edit in a clean, solid-color circle easily enough.  But I'd like to use the same circle, in the same position, on every portrait so they're all as close to the same size as possible.  How can I do this?  Is there a way to apply the circle's layer to every image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a layer mask on a layer group containing all the images. Switch each layer on/off as you require. Then you can duplicate the group, move the group, remove unused layers, etc.

An example

[image]